# AutoMapper .ForMember for collection

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

I have entity `Request` and model `RequestModel`

```
public class RequestModel : BaseModel
{
    public IEnumerable <int> Recipients { get; set; }
}

public class Request : IIdent
{
    public virtual ICollection <RequestComment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class RequestComment : IIdent
{
   [ForeignKey("User")]
   public int? UserId { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create mapping for `Recipients`

```
CreateMap<Request, RequestModel>()
      .ForMember(d => d.Recipients, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Comments.Select(x => x.UserId )))
```

But I get exception :

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException was caught _HResult=-2146233088 HResult=-2146233088  IsTransient=false  Message= Mapping types:
>   Request -> IEnumerable`1
>   AttManager.Data.Request -> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
>   Destination path:
>   RequestModel.Recipients.Recipients
>   Source value:
>   AttManager.Data.Request

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem comes when you try to convert an `IEnumerable<RequestComment>` to `IEnumerable<int>`, so *Automapper* is going to try to find an conversion between `RequestComment` to `int`, but is not defined.

You can define the conversion from `RequestComment` to `int` like this:

```
.CreateMap<RequestComment, int>().ConvertUsing(rm => rm.UserId ?? 0);
```

And the map between the requests models:

```
.CreateMap<Request, RequestModel>()
.ForMember(d => d.Recipients, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Comments))
```

Also, another way to solve your problem is defining an `AfterMap` operation:

```
.CreateMap<Request, RequestModel>()
.AfterMap((r, rm) => rm.Recipients = new List<int>(r.Comments.Select(c => c.UserId ?? 0)));
```

I just add `?? 0` because `UserId` type is `int?`, so need to be converted to `int` for `Recipients` property.

Comment: Thanks! First way works fine, but with 2nd I have some troubles.. I also get exception in mapping. Should I add code like `.ForMember(d => d.Recipients, o => o.PreserveAndIgnore())` before using `.AfterMap()` ?

Comment: @demo: I just tested in-memory with single maps, but if you're using queryable projections `AfterMap` isn't an option, sorry for that.